# PHP PSR Whitespaces before and after concatenate operator question (dot)

Tags: php

I am looking for information about best practices when programming at PHP. I could not find any information about the space before and after the concatenate operator "dot" (.).

```
$var = "Hello " . $name . " How you doing? today: " . $day;
```

Maybe there is another standard that specifies this but I didn't found it.

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: Haven't used it before, but [`phpcs`](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) or some other code analyzer could probably guide you here.

Comment: I do, but I think I need to add some configuration for having the PSR-12 extended coding style, or some kind or custom rule maybe...

Comment: `phpcs --standard=PSR12 /path/to/code-directory`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PSR-2 doesn't cover a coding style for operators. They are listed in [the conclusion](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#7-conclusion) as "**intentionally omitted**".

[PSR-12: Extended Coding Style](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) expands on PSR-2, and does include guidance around this:

> 6.2. Binary operators
> All binary arithmetic, comparison, assignment, bitwise, logical, string, and type operators MUST be preceded and followed by at least one space:

```
if ($a === $b) {
    $foo = $bar ?? $a ?? $b;
} elseif ($a > $b) {
    $foo = $a + $b * $c;
}
```

See https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#62-binary-operators

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: concat is not a binary operator?

Comment: concat is a binary (acts on two operands) string operator, and thus covered by this rule

Answer (score 2):

See psr-12
[link](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#62-binary-operators)

6.2. Binary operators
All binary arithmetic, comparison, assignment, bitwise, logical, string, and type operators MUST be preceded and followed by at least one space:

Comment: That link doesn't address string concatenation - it's specifically under 'binary operators', and the examples specifically don't address string concatenation.

Comment: @kimsal Read first paragraph of [String Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), in short concatenation operator ('.') is one of the string operators thus follow the same.